# i have an issue with an "autosuggestbox" on release deployment

Tags: vb.net, xaml, visual-studio-2019

I am developing a very basic uwp application with Visual Studio 2019 community. I use an autosuggestbox to allow the user to find entries that come up often.

When I deploy the application in debug mode the autosuggestbox works perfectly. If I start to type the beginning of one of the terms of the list then this one appears well in suggestion. On the other hand as soon as I deploy the application in release mode, typing in the autosuggestbox causes the application of the second letter to crash.

There is an exception that appears in release and no errors of any kind in debug.

Suddenly I wonder if there is not a problem / bug with this particular version of Visual Studio.

The exception is (in french sorry about that):

> Exception non gérée à 0x00007FFB43F02EC0 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) dans
>   mesCoursUWP.exe*: 0xC000027B: Une exception interne de l’application
>   s’est produite (paramètres*: 0x000002677AA56290, 0x0000000000000003).
>   a eu lieu*

In the debug window I have this:

> Exception levée*: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' dans
>   System.Private.CoreLib.dll Exception levée*:
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' dans System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>   Exception levée*: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' dans
>   System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB404801F5) ReturnHr(1) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB4048017A) ReturnHr(2) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB404801F5) ReturnHr(3) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB404801F5) ReturnHr(4) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB404801F5) ReturnHr(5) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable. Exception levée*: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' dans
>   System.Private.CoreLib.dll Exception levée*:
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' dans System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>   Exception levée*: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' dans
>   System.Private.CoreLib.dll Exception levée*:
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' dans System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>   Exception levée*: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' dans
>   System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB404801F5) ReturnHr(6) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB4048017A) ReturnHr(7) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB404801F5) ReturnHr(8) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB404801F5) ReturnHr(9) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB4048017A) ReturnHr(10) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB404801F5) ReturnHr(11) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB4048017A) ReturnHr(12) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB404801F5) ReturnHr(13) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB404801F5) ReturnHr(14) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB4048017A) ReturnHr(15) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB404801F5) ReturnHr(16) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB4048017A) ReturnHr(17) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB404801F5) ReturnHr(18) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB4048017A) ReturnHr(19) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB404801F5) ReturnHr(20) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB404801F5) ReturnHr(21) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB4048017A) ReturnHr(22) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB404801F5) ReturnHr(23) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB4048017A) ReturnHr(24) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB404801F5) ReturnHr(25) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB404801F5) ReturnHr(26) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB4048017A) ReturnHr(27) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable. Exception levée*: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' dans
>   System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB404801F5) ReturnHr(28) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB4048017A) ReturnHr(29) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB404801F5) ReturnHr(30) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable.
>   onecoreuap\windows\wgi\winrt\display\displaycommon.cpp(411)\Windows.Graphics.dll!00007FFB404804B0:
>   (caller: 00007FFB404801F5) ReturnHr(31) tid(530) 80070490 Élément
>   introuvable. Exception levée*: 'System.MissingMemberException' dans
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Comment: The exception is `FileNotFound`. Are you accessing a file after someone has entered more than one char in the autosuggestbox? It appears that a file that is present in the `Debug` folder has not been also copied in the `Release` folder (or a resource file is missing).

Comment: At that time when I am in the autosuggestbox I do not make any access to any file. Suggestions that should appear are given directly in the code.